# jQuery $.map() returning a new element

Tags: jquery, dictionary

i have the following code:

```
$('#test')
    .append($.map(this.items, function (item, index) {
        return '<li><input type="checkbox" value="' + item.key + '">' item.title + '</li>'
    }).join(''));
```

but i would like it to look more like this:

```
$('#test')
    .append($.map(this.items, function (item, index) {
        return $('<li/>').append('<input/>', {type: 'checkbox', value: item.key}).text(item.title)
    });
```

but this dosent seem to work.
anyone can help?

**EDIT**
since it seems that the answers cannot apply in the RL situation (i made the code short to explain) here is my actual code:

```
_RenderCheckbox: function () {
    $('<ul/>')
        .appendTo(this.element)
        .addClass('widget')
        .append($('<input>').attr({ type: 'text', class: 'field', 'data-map': this.element.attr("data-map") }))
        .append($.map(this.items, function (item, index) {
                return '<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="' + item.key + '">' + item.parent + item.title + '</label></li>'
        }).join(''));
},
```

this is part of a jquery ui widget i am developing.

Comment: `$.map` returns `Array`. `.append()` does not accept `Array` as its first argument. You will find it much easier to loop with `$.each(this.items, ...)`, progressively building and appending `<li>` elements as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.text()` replaces the contents of your `<li>`. You'll have to `append`/`prepend` your element:

```
return $('<li />', {
    text: item.title
}).append($('<input />', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    value: item.key
}));
```

Also, don't use `join()`. Just put this code in `$.each`:

```
var $test = $('#test');

$.each(this.items, function(item, index) {
    var $li = $('<li />', {
        text: item.title
    }).appendTo($test);

    $('<input />', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        value: item.key
    }).appendTo($li);
});
```

And if you prefer huge one-liners:

```
var $test = $('#test');

$.each(this.items, function(item, index) {
    $('<li />', {
        text: item.title
    }).appendTo($test)
      .append($('<input />', {
        type: 'checkbox',
        value: item.key
    }));
});
```

Comment: @Dementic: It is for me: `[<li>​bar​</li>​]`

Comment: can you jsfiddle it? since i get back `[object Object]`

Comment: @Dementic: Don't use `.join('')`. See my answer for the proper way of doing it.

Comment: @Dementic: `join()` is your problem. It converts your objects to strings, which isn't what you want.

Comment: So this append operation is only possible with `.each()` and not with `map()`?

Comment: @Forethinker: It's possible with `.map()`, but that's not what `.map()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried splicing things up to avoid returning the wrong object?
Havent tried your code tough this might work:

```
$('#test')
.append($.map(this.items, function (item, index) {
    var ret = $('<li/>');
    var input = ret.append('<input/>', {type: 'checkbox', value: item.key});
    input.text(item.title);
    return ret;
});
```

Comment: your code returns a joined list of `[object Object]` which is the same problem i had before.